# Error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year' when querying a model

Tags: python, django

I get startdate and enddate, but they are passed as a string. How do I convert them to a date?

```
    startdate = request.POST["startdate"]
    enddate = request.POST["enddate"]
    queryset = paidparking.objects.all()
    qsstats = QuerySetStats(queryset, date_field='expirationdate')
    values = qsstats.time_series(startdate, enddate, interval='days')
    return render(request, 'index/template.html', {'values': values})
```

Error in:     values = qsstats.time_series(startdate, enddate, interval='days')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startdate` and `enddate` are *strings*, not `datetime` objects. You need to parse these, so something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

startdate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['startdate'], '%Y-%m-%d')
enddate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['enddate'], '%Y-%m-%d')
queryset = paidparking.objects.all()
qsstats = QuerySetStats(queryset, date_field='expirationdate')
values = qsstats.time_series(startdate, enddate, interval='days')
return render(request, 'index/template.html', {'values': values})
```

The format here (`'%Y-%m-%d'`) might be different, depending on how the date is formatted as string.

I would however advise to work with a [**`Form`** [Djang-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/). These forms make it convenient to parse, clean and validate input.

Comment: They don't change the format for some reason     startdate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['startdate'], '%d.%m.%Y')
    enddate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['enddate'], '%d.%m.%Y')
    print(startdate)
    print(enddate), The format should be 31.05.2021 and it is in 2021-05-31 00: 00:00

Comment: @Илья: then he format is `datetime.strptime('2021-05-31 00: 00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H: %M:%S')`. Although I find the space between `00:` and `00` quite "strange".

Comment: @Илья: with `datetime.strftime(my_datetime_obj, '%d.%m.%Y')` But normally that is something that is handled by the template, and often is determined by the *locale* of the browser, such that people that belong to a culture that is different, will also see a different presentation of the date.]

Comment: startdate = datetime.strftime(request.POST['startdate'], '%d.%m.%Y')
    enddate = datetime.strftime(request.POST['enddate'], '%d.%m.%Y')  I get an error TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Comment: @Илья: of course you will first need to *parse* strings in the `request.POST` to a datetime, and *then* you can *format* these.

Comment: And how to do it? Can I give you an example?

Comment: @Илья: it's already *in* the answer, with `strptime`, you convert a *string* to a *datetime* object, so there is no need to do formatting.

Comment: I do     startdate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['startdate'], '%d.%m.%Y')
    enddate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['enddate'], '%d.%m.%Y') But I get it 2021-04-30 00:00:00
2021-05-12 00:00:00

Comment: @Илья: yes but these are *not* strings, that the entire point. These are `datetime` objects, and simply when you *print* these, they will format it as `year-month-day hour:minute:second`.

Comment: And if you do not print them, then they are in the format %d.%m.%Y?

Comment: @Илья: noooo... these are datetime objects, not strings. You can for example call `.year` on the outcome of the `strpformat`, you can not do that on the `request.POST['startdate']`.

Comment: I don't understand how I can put it all in the format % d.% M.% Y

Comment: @Илья: but you should **not** do that. The `time_series` does **not** expect strings, it expects `datetime` objects, so that means that once these are parsed, the `time_series` can do processing on that.

Comment: I have a date in the database in the format 05.05.2021 and check for compliance with this date, and it is in the format %Y-%m-%d

Comment: @Илья: you should use a `DateTimeField` or a `DateField` in the database, *not* a string. If you use a `DateField`, then, as said before, it will only *present* data in that format, but internally it is stored in a totally different way: as a binary encoded number of ticks.

Comment: I have expirationdate = models.DateField(null=True)

Comment: @Илья: well if you then store it as a `date` object, then that will not result in any trouble. You can convert a `datetime` (the thing we parsed here), to a `date` object by calling the `.date()` method on that `datetime` object.